# What are the possible units for CPU usage in the kubernetes /apis/events.k8s.io/v1beta1 endpoint?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to get the CPU usage from the `/apis/events.k8s.io/v1beta1` endpoint in the kubernetes internal api.

I run the following command

`kubectl proxy --port=8080`

Then load the url http://localhost:8080/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods and get a response similar to this one

```
{
  "kind": "PodMetricsList",
  "apiVersion": "metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "name-of-the-container-667656d796-p586s",
        "namespace": "namespace-name",
        "selfLink": "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods/name-of-the-container-667656d796-p586s",
        "creationTimestamp": "2019-11-20T21:34:02Z"
      },
      "timestamp": "2019-11-20T21:33:02Z",
      "window": "30s",
      "containers": [
        {
          "name": "name-of-the-container",
          "usage": {
            "cpu": "350748682n",
            "memory": "238860Ki"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The cpu value is `350748682n`.  From [this discussion](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/metric-server-cpu-and-memory-units/7497) `n` is "1/1000000000 (1 billionth) of a cpu"

I am also seeing values like `14513u`

I have reviewed the [quantity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/glossary/?all=true#term-quantity) definition but do not see anything referencing `u`

What are all the possible units used to report this metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`u` is a simplification of the lowercase Greek mu (μ) which means 10^-6, aka "micro-cpus". The unit is always the same, it's in terms of CPU cores. Metrics-server tries to report in nano-cpus for maximum accuracy, but if the number won't fit in an int64, it will change the scaling factor until it fits.

Comment: will it also report in millicpus (m)?

Comment: Like I said, it will keep bumping the scale until the number fits in an int64. In theory it could use any scaling factor, though eventually we would be talking about more cores than exist on the planet :)